# Wanderlust / Emacs -- filters -- format of the string /since:X#ofDays/%inbox

Tags: emacs, imap

I was able to find the following two working examples of the string `/since:...` to configure some folder filters in Wanderlust (`.folders`), but I cannot find anything to define a set number days -- e.g., `/since:last-7-days/$inbox` or `/from:2012-01-01-to-2012-12-31/%inbox`.

The support team at my website provider (liquidweb) has no idea -- apparently they use Google search also when faced with a situation like this.  I would think there must be a way to further define the filters.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.  I found something on Google for mu4e (*not* Wanderlust) which uses something similar -- it does not give me any error messages, but no emails appear in the filtered folders:  `/date:today..now/...` and `/date:7d..now/...`.

Here is the working configuration for Wanderlust:

```
/since:yesterday/%INBOX.Sent      "Sent -- since yesterday"

/since:2013-07-01/%INBOX.Sent     "Sent -- since 07-01-2013"

/flag:unread/%inbox               "INBOX -- unread"
%inbox                            "INBOX -- all"
%INBOX.Sent                       "Sent"
%INBOX.Junk                       "Junk"
%INBOX.Trash                      "Trash"
%INBOX.Drafts                     "Drafts"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have no idea why this didn't come up earlier in any of my seemingly endless Google searches, but it sure is golden:  http://www.gohome.org/wl/doc/wl_23.html

```
Filter Folder

A folder to access virtual folder which collects all messages that satisfy a condition.

Format:

`/' condition `/' target-folder

In the condition part, you can specify following.

    Partial filter: `first:number', `last:number' first: number messages are picked from top of folder. last: number messages are picked from bottom of folder. Example:

    /last:10/-fj.os.linux -> Latest 10 messages from -fj.os.linux are picked.
    /first:20/%inbox      -> First 20 messages from %inbox are picked.

    Date filter: `since:date', `before:date' since: only messages arrived since date are picked. before: only messages arrived before date are picked. You can specify following as date.

    yesterday ->  a day before today.
    lastweek  ->  same day of last week.
    lastmonth ->  same day of last month.
    lastyear  ->  same day of last year.
    numberdaysago -> number days ago. (e.x. '3daysago')
    day-month-year -> specify date directly (ex. 1-Nov-1998)

    Example:

    /since:3daysago/+inbox -> messages arrived since 3 days ago in +inbox
                              are picked.
    /before:yesterday/+inbox -> messages arrived before yesterday in +inbox
                              are picked.

    Field filter: `field:value' All messages that have field and its value is value are picked. field and value are case insensitive. Example:

    /from:teranisi/+inbox -> In +inbox, messages which have From: field
                             and its value includes "teranisi" string are picked.
    /body:foo/%inbox      -> In %inbox, messages which have "foo" text
                             are picked.

    Compound condition If you combine conditions by character `|', it is considered as OR condition. `&' is considered as AND condition, likewise. Condition can be grouped by parentheses (`(', and `)'). `/tocc:xxxx/' is an abbreviation of `/to:xxxx|cc:xxxx/'. `/!tocc:xxxx/' is an abbreviation of `/!to:xxxx&!cc:xxxx/'. Example:

    /from:teranisi&!to:teranisi/+inbox
                          -> In +inbox, messages are picked if the message's
                             From: field includes "teranisi" and
                             To: field doesn't include "teranisi".

    /tocc:"Yuuichi Teranishi"/+inbox
                          -> In +inbox, messages are picked if the
                             message's To: field or Cc: field includes
                             "Yuuichi Teranishi".

    /(from:yt|from:teranisi)&subject:report/+inbox
                          -> In +inbox, messages are picked if the message's
                             From: field includes "yt" or "teranisi", and
                            Subject includes "report".

Tip for string description:

Space character, `"', `/',`)',`|' and `&' should be enclosed with `"' in value string. (`"' should be escaped with `\' in it). You can enclose the string with `"' even it does not contain these characters.

Advanced example:

*%inbox,/from:teranisi/%inbox@server
       -> Messages in %inbox or
          message is in the %inbox@server folder and it's From field
          includes "teranisi" are collected.

/last:100//to:teranisi/*+inbox,%inbox
       -> Latest 100 messages which is in the +inbox or %inbox folder
          and To: field matches "teranisi".

/from:hogehoge//last:20//tocc:teranisi/%#mh/inbox@localhost
       -> Pick messages which have From: field and it includes "hogehoge"
          from latest 20 messages in the %#mh/inbox@localhost
          and To: or Cc: field includes "teranisi".
```